# Where can I set how the pagination links render?

Tags: craft3, url, pagination

I have inherited a Craft 3 project in which the pagination links render with a query parameter "page": `https://mysite.com/blog/?page=2` but this makes crawlers like HREFS to ignore the Next and Prev links (resulting in over 100 "orphan" pages).

Where can I reset my pagination links to the standard `https://mysite.com/blog/p2` format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete the overridden pageTrigger config setting in your `config/general.php` file:

https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/config/config-settings.html#pagetrigger

Comment: Awesome, you saved my life.